# Xamarin Forms - Ordered List and ArgumentOutOfRange

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been fighting with this exception (and subsequent hard crash) for about a day now. I have a ListView in Xamarin Forms that does grouping headers. As much as I can gather from the Call Stack, the error is occurring because of the grouping. I verified this by removing the grouping from the ListView and the app displays the data without crashing. I've even diff'd the code back a few weeks and nothing stands out. <s>This also only occurs on a new launch and subsequent launches don't throw this exception or crash.</s>

How else might I go about further debugging and resolving this?

[image: Exception stack trace]

List View XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewItems"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsGrouped}"
            GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key.DisplayText}"
            IsGroupingEnabled="true">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <cells:MyGroupHeaderView/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <cells:ItemCellView />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

MyGroupHeaderView XAML

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Label Text="{Binding Key.DisplayText}">
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Grouping C# Code

```
var result = from s in myItems
    orderby s.ItemDateTime
    group s by s.GetSortGroupInfo()
    into itemGroup
    select new Grouping<GroupInfo, ItemViewModel>(itemGroup.Key, itemGroup);
```

GroupInfo class (used for sorting and display)

```
public class GroupInfo
{
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }

    public int SortValue { get; set; }
}
```

Bound Property and Setter

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<Grouping<GroupInfo, ItemViewModel>> ItemsGrouped { get; }
    = new ObservableRangeCollection<Grouping<GroupInfo, StopViewModel>>();

this.ItemsGrouped.ReplaceRange(
    this.MyItems.GroupByDate()
        .OrderBy(f => f.Key.SortValue)
        .ToList());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Turns out when I updated James Montemagno's Xam.Plugin.Geolocator from 3.04 to 4.01, it also switched from PCL to .NET Standard. When I rolled it back, ListView grouping is working again. Unfortunately, I can't get GeoLocation to work with 3.04, and somehow, of all things, I get the above error with 4.01.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is that [TemplatedItemsList](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/TemplatedItemsList.cs) isn't handling the [Reset](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction/) generated by ReplaceRange well.

As a short-term workaround, you can avoid the crash by not using ReplaceRange:

```
ItemsGrouped.Clear();
foreach (var item in MyItems.GroupByDate().OrderBy(f => f.Key.SortValue))
{
    ItemsGrouped.Add(item);
}
```

Or set the [caching strategy](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/#Caching_Strategy) to recycle:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewItems"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsGrouped}"
        IsGroupingEnabled="true"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
```

Interestingly if you follow the call chain you come to `UnhookItem` which has this comment:

```
//Hack: the cell could still be visible on iOS because the cells are reloaded after this unhook 
//this causes some visual updates caused by a null datacontext and default values like IsVisible
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS && CachingStrategy == ListViewCachingStrategy.RetainElement)
    await Task.Delay(100);
item.BindingContext = null;
```

The crash to me looks to be caused by an attempt to re-render the template because the binding context has changed ... so maybe this hack is also applicable to Android ...

You are setting both the `GroupDisplayBinding` and the `GroupHeaderTemplate` in the sample code above ... I assume because you were experimenting ... you should only have one set at a time ... using `GroupDisplayBinding` would also avoid the  issue I expect.

Comment: I changed ReplaceRange, took out GroupDisplayBinding, and added CachingStrategy, but it's still crashing. I can debug and step through all our code without issue. The exception seems to be happening on render.

Comment: Can you post a complete minimal standalone example.  I was able to reproduce your error, but was unable to reproduce when caching strategy was recycle, or when not using ReplaceRange.